# Google sheets script getRange arguments problem

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a little script in Google Tabs that watches a column and when any cell in that column is changed it writes the current date to the cell next to the cell changed.

I've been looking for the solution on a dozen of sites and modified my code accordingly but I keep running into the same problem. The .getRange() script works fine if I provide a definite cell as argument, like .getRange('I3'), however it does nothing when I try to use coordinates instead e.g .getRange(3,9). This really is a problem because I need to use the row-number of the changed cell to write the date to the cell next to it.

```
function onEdit(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == 9){

    var date = sheet.getRange('J2'); //current date is in cell J2
    var row = sheet.getRange(editedCell).getRow();
    sheet.getRange(row,10).setValue(date);
  }
}
```

I tried breaking the code to smaller bits in order to find out which part keeps failing and found that the .getRange won't accept neither variables nor integer values as coordinates. It only operates with cells, while on every forum I searched coordinates were used.

I'm open to any suggestions regarding this problem.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Won't work is not a problem description. Quote the exact error. See [mre] and [ask]

Comment: There is no error message. There is simply no result in the table I could work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.columnStart==9){
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked just fine. I was stuck with the classic ways but this is much more elegant :)